# 水面*が*月を映していた: Is に interchangeable?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に, particle-が

> 澄んだ水面 **が** 月を映していた。

Under the 映す entry in a dictionary (ルミナス、研究社), I found the sample sentence in question among others. However, I couldn't understand why only in this particular sentence is が used in favor of に.

For instance, there were also these two sentences listed right beside the one above:

> 彼女は鏡 **に** 顔を映してみた。
>   彼はスクリーン **に** スライドを次々に映した。

Both of which employed に as I normally would expect.

The only plausible reason I can think of is that the first sentence does not have an animate subject (月), whereas the others do (彼女、彼). I do not believe this is the factor though.

Interestingly, for the verb 映す's intransitive counterpart－映る－they gave the following sample sentence:

> 月が湖水 **に** 映っていた。

**Question:**
Can が be replaced by に in the first sentence (i.e. 水面に)? If not, what is the grammar at work that prevents us to do so?

ご教授どうもありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change が to に, but the meaning changes and it may become a bit odd sentence. If you change が to に, the problem is who is the subject. If "someone" is the subject of the sentence, it means "someone reflects the moon on the water surface (with a mirror or something like that)".